# problem with aisleriot solitare since upgrading to 12.04

Tags: games

The game can be downloaded but all the previous options like "re-start, close, etc. are not available. In order to get out of the game, I have to re-boot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing? If you don't have any saved games/statistics you need, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge aisleriot
sudo apt-get install aisleriot
```

The above command will attempt to remove all config files associated with the game, which may be causing the issues. If you have saved games/statistics you want to keep, try:

---

```
sudo apt-get remove aisleriot
sudo apt-get install aisleriot
```

If that doesn't work, please provide a screenshot of the issue.